# In java, why is Observable's setChanged() protected?

Tags: java, design-patterns

If a java class, say `classA`, is extending `classB`, it cannot extend `Observable`. But if the `setChanged()` function were public, instead of protected, we can use composition to create an instance of `Observable` in `classA`.

I wonder what was the thought process behind making `setChanged()` protected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `setChanged` and such were public, then anything could change them. Only the object itself should be able to change them.

To handle your case of `ClassA` that extends `ClassB`, you'd probably want to have a method on `ClassA` that returns an `Observable`; within `ClassA`, the observable is an inner class that extends `Observable` and which only `ClassA` has access to.

This is very much the way collections and `Iterator` work.